# Bootstrap row is not stacking divs on small screen sizes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap row for two divs. I want them to be in a row on large devices but stacked on small devices. Bootstrap isn't stacking it on small devices it's still keeping both of them at 50%. The divs I am referring to are the ones with an ID of left and themebox.

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="left" class="col-sm-12 col-lg-3">
     <br>
     <br>
     <h3> Mine Style</h3>
     <br>
     <br>
    <button id="customize">Customize</button>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-9" id="themebox"></div>



#themebox{
  height: 500px;
  background-color: white;
  float: right;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 45px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}
.row{
 margin-left: 0 !important;
 margin-right:0 !important;
 }
```

Comment: Mine is stacking fine. I see you are missing two closing `divs`. Maybe that is your problem?

Comment: Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you wanted this?

```css
#themebox{
  height: 500px;
  background-color: white;
  float: right;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 45px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}
.row{
 margin-left: 0 !important;
 margin-right:0 !important;
 }

h3 {
  margin:20px 0 !important;
}

#left {
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-start;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) { 
  #left {
  align-items:center;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:flex-start;
}
  
  #customize {
    margin:0 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="left" class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-3">
     <h3> Mine Style</h3>
    <button id="customize">Customize</button>
   </div>
   <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-9" id="themebox"></div>
```